# How to hide the iPhone keyboard? resignFirstResponder does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I have the following code...

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  //some code here...

NSInteger theTag = textField.tag;   //I set the tag to 5 in IB

    if (theTag == 5) { 
        //self.showDatePicker;
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }   
}
```

The problem is, the keyboard never disappears.  Another thing to note is that I have some other methods that move the view up and down based on the position of the textfield selected.  Maybe that's messing up my Responder, but I just don't understand why the keyboard won't go away.

Also, I might just be doing this all wrong.  I want this textField, when pressed, to hide the keyboard and show a date picker.  Should this be in a different method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS 3.2+, I'd suggest looking into `UITextField`'s `inputView` property.  You can assign a custom view (i.e. a data picker) to be displayed when the text field becomes the first responder instead of the keyboard.

Comment: Looks great, I'll check into it.  Sound just like what I was looking for! :)